# Can we stop event hub capture for time being & re-enable?

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azure-eventhub

I have the avro files generated by Event Hub Capture & stored in ADLS Gen1. Now I would like to migrate all these files ( size ~6 TB) to ADLS Gen2. During migration process, I don't want event hub capture to generate *new avro files* & place in old Gen1 path hence wondering if there is a way to temporarily stop "Capture" & re-enable it back post data migration & reconciliation activities (i.e. changing path to ADLS Gen2) ?

If I "disable" Capture using UI , is there any chance of data loss on re-enabling the setting ?

P.S. I am using event hub dedicated cluster & it has retention period of 90 days. Also,can't ask publisher to stop sending events during this migration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can disable the capture temporarily. However, make sure your retention period is long enough - 90 days for dedicated, that no data is purged w/o being captured.

See the capture description and the 'enabled' bool here > https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.eventhub/namespaces/eventhubs?tabs=bicep#capturedescription

See the overview of retention policy feature here > https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-features#event-retention